# Block Diagram Reduction

Tags: control-system, system

[image]

Could anyone help me with the start, I don't how to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: -

State what Y equals by naming node values: -

Y = aC - bE where a is the node_value on the input of C and b is the node_value on the input of E. Then you'd likely evaluate a from b and Y via D

So, a = c - DY then, go back to the first equation and get rid of the a term.

Just keep doing this and it should fall-out.

Answer (score 1):

My approach for solving the problem is as follows:

1.) Redraw the circuit with the goal not having any cross-couplings. That means: We have only simple feedback loops.

2.) Therefore: Shift the input node for E to the right (after the summing junction). As a consequence the function of this block now must be (E+D)

3.) Shift the input of B to the left (before the summing junction). Now, this block must have the function (B-D) instead of B only.

4.) Now we have one simple forward path (E+D) in parallel to C resulting in (C+D+E) and two simple negative feedback loops which can be solved **separately** (Blacks formula).

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way in which you could use [these rules](http://www.roymech.co.uk/Related/Control/Blocks.html) to solve the problem. Here is one:

- Move the input of B to the left, before the summing point.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff6O0q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Move C to the left, before the summing point.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI71Y2.png)</sup>

- Interchange the summing points.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f16qLX.png)</sup>

- Simplifications: blocks in parallel(C - E) and feedback loop in CD.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpcw6C.png)</sup>

- Move (C - E)/(1 + CD) to the left, before the take-off point.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuwZos.png)</sup>

- Simplification.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1TgO1.png)</sup>

- Simplify the feedback loop and there you have it: $$\frac{AC - AE}{1 + CD + AB + ABDE}$$